# image quality is missing while using thumb.php

Tags: php

I am using thumb.php to restrict image sizes.

```
<img src="thumb.php?src=<?php echo $imgurl; ?>&h=150&w=180&z=0" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="180" height="150" />
```

The problem is image quality. If i do not use thumb.php and mention the width and height attribute directly in the image tag, the quality is good but while using thumb.php the image looks a little blur.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Please refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aM7Fy/. Sorry i just pasted the code and didn't know the other means to provide the code to you.

Comment: You must be kidding to paste the code that way. Just give reference where you obtained it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw on your script the quality param and it's **q**, append it to the url

```
<img src="thumb.php?src=<?php echo $imgurl; ?>&h=150&w=180&z=0&q=100" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="180" height="150" />
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I got idea from your answer.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the original image and a resized one?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this using the sharpen parameter.

&h=150&w=180&z=0&q=100&s=100" alt="" width="180" height="150" />

Thanks.